# Incorrect form fields in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, jaws-screen-reader

I use inputs in data table for search by column value in "columnheader" and custom actions(a or button with script) in "gridcell".

The main problem is JAWS's "Select form fields"(Insert + F5) all forms fields get united in one long field.

For example IE shows: QuestionsSort by question nameActionsInformation about Jaws questionEdit Jaws questionDelete Jaws question table. Chrome shows: Questions table.

Template of table:

```html
<table role="grid">
  <caption>Questions</caption>
  <thead role="rowgroup">
    <tr role="row">
      <th role="columnheader">
        <a aria-label="Sort by question name">
          <span>Question name</span>
        </a>
      </th>
      <th role="columnheader">
        Actions
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody role="rowgroup">
   <tr role="row">
     <td role="gridcell">
       <button aria-label="Information about Jaws question">Jaws</button> 
     </td>
     <td role="gridcell">
      <a aria-label="Edit Jaws question">Edit</a>
      <a aria-label="Delete Jaws question">Delete</a>
     </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Gridcells connected via headers attribute and work fine.
I tried use spans with aria-labelledby for cells but this is doesn't help.
Also I can't change template of table to much.

Comment: If the test is displayed on the screen then try to make a test with 'aria-labelledby' instead of 'aria-label'. if the issue persists then I suggest you try to provide a clear example that can produce the issue. The above description and example are a little confusing.  Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I am able to produce the issue. Not sure what causes this issue. I try to refer to the docs but did not get any solution for this issue. I suggest you try to contact the JAWS support and check whether this issue is caused by the JAWS app or not.